# Image Pop Up when hover with icon appears

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

so I had troubles with this one for quite a long time and couldn't find a solution, will be glad if anyone could help me with it. So basically what I have troubles with: I have an image with hover made by icon, I want to get image Pop Up when this icon appears and user clicks on it.
Here's my JSFiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/rissutei/wqyd48mj/17/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="galleryPicture">
      <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/02/08/17/24/fantasy-2049567__480.jpg" alt="">
      <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
    </div>





    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/9df2c8dd8e.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

```
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
} 
 
 img {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
div.galleryPicture {
  padding:20px;
  margin-bottom: 35px;
  position: relative;

  &:hover img {
    opacity: 0.8;
    filter: brightness(40%);
  }

  i {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 35%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    font-size: 34px;
    color: #ffffff;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    line-height: 60px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -35%) scale(0);
    transition: transform 0.5s 0ms cubic-bezier(0.6, -0.28, 0.735, 0.045);
  }

  &:hover i {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
    transition: all 300ms 100ms cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
  }
}
```

Comment: So basically, if the user clicks `<i class="fas fa-plus"></i>` you want a div to appear? You haven't implemented a basic click handler yet, where exactly are you stuck? https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/0Lvqnowk/

Comment: What do you mean by image Pop Up

Comment: not a div, but a Pop Up window with the image behind that Icon

Comment: @ChrisG Im stuck with finding solution to how I can do this, I just need a code that I can use, because im just starting to use JQuery and Javascript

Comment: @iunfixit smthng like this https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modal_images.asp

Comment: If you have just started learning JS, you need to simply keep learning. "I just need a code" is the wrong approach.

Comment: [Also, please do not use or link to w3schools.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280478/why-not-w3schools-com)

Comment: @ChrisG Yeah, I know that, but I need to make this thing work till tomorrow, and I had already spent around 5-6 days searching something similar with what Im asking here.

Comment: What exactly is `a Pop Up window with the image behind that Icon`? And how do you figure showing a div is not what you're looking for?

Comment: The w3schools link correctly shows what he meant and clarifies it, the question is tagged on html and css too and they might not know the need for Javascript

Comment: @ChrisG alright, sorry, my bad, Im new to stackoverflow, so I don't really know how to reply to other people's comments, what's allowed or not here etc.

Comment: No worries, but this is not really a beginner's tutorial site. See [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/5734311)

Comment: @ChrisG got you